# System error(10054) - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: networking, connection, tcp, windows-server-2012-r2, reset

I run a dialer made by Altitude Software. Few people are likely to be familiar with this product, so please bear with me.

**Problem:**
The Altitude dialer software is an application running on Windows Server 2012 R2. The OS is virtualized on VMware 6.7.

Agents/clients connect to the Altitude dialer (server) via a Windows application called Altitude uAgent.

From time to time the Altitude server log is filled up with thousands of these errors: System error(10054) - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

As far as I can understand this error derives from the operating system.

Server is placed at our hosting partner and all clients are connected up via VPN on the network level (not VPN-clients on PCs).

When this error happens no users are able to work properly.

The challenge is that neither the hosting partner, nor the creator of the application (Altitude Software) are able to see what's going on. Our hosting partner says they can't see anything wrong with the network. Altitude says that they can see the error, but don't know what causes it. They say it's something outside of their application. The situation is unbearable.

Clients use Windows 10 Pro.

**What we have tried:**

We have tried to reinstall the Windows Server 2012 R2 OS from scratch, and then reinstall the Altitude server. After two weeks the problem returned. The server local FW is disabled, and there is no antivirus software or similar installed.

We've increased the number of TCP-connections

Situation is unbearable, and noone seems to be able to shed some light in this case. Any ideas of to pursue this error?

Comment: Try this [registry fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/981344/an-application-may-receive-the-10054-error-when-the-application-receiv).

Comment: Hello,

I can try, but the article you are referring to talks about Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2. We have Server 2012 R2. Also I am not sure whether we have a TDI-filter installed. We don't have any antivirus on the server (it's behind strong firewalls and not open to the outside world).

Do you still recon it's worth a try?

Comment: You can always undo if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I am working as a Technical Engineer in Altitude and faced the same error in a customer environment. The error 10054 itself is a system error that is faced due to socket exhaustion at the system level. I was able to resolve the problem by following actions.

1. Altitude uCI is using on random ports/sockets for interprocess communication and to communicate with other components. Please follow the below commands for reference to configure/increase the range. By default the range of allowed port is only about 16000 for TCP/UDP connection.

netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=8200 num=57336

netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=8200 num=57336

verify the new socket allocation executing below commands.

netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp

netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport udp

2. Add below entries in the registry where Altitude Assisted Server is installed.

This will increase time to wait delay and the number of TCP connections.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TEZI.png)

Regards:
Umer

Comment: Hi Umer, thanks for your reply! As far as I remember we did in fact increase the allowed number of TCP-connection without help. I can't remember whether we also increased the UDP.

The problem actually disappeared when we patched the system to a higher level. I can't remember since this is a while ago.

At the moment I'm no longer working with Altitude products. Thanks Umer.